# New Google Sign-In API - refresh token

Tags: android, google-signin

### Problem

I am trying to use the [New Google Sign-In API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity) for authenticating with my own backend server. Every call to my server contains the idToken jwt as a Bearer token. On the backend side, I validate the token by checking the signature, and checking if the token is expired or not. The problem is that the [New Google Sign-In API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity) returns jwts with 1 hour expiration time, but I could not find any way to refresh the token.

### Questions

1. Is this a valid/safe way to authenticate the user with my backend server?
2. How do I get a fresh id token without the user having to go through the sign-in flow again?

### Code

**How I get the idToken client side**

```kotlin
fun showSignInDialog() {
  val request = GetSignInIntentRequest.builder()
    .setServerClientId(GOOGLE_SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
    .build()

  Identity.getSignInClient(context)
    .getSignInIntent(request)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
      googleSignInLauncher.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(it).build())
    }
}

fun handleSignInResult(result: ActivityResult) {
  val credential = Identity.getSignInClient(context)
    .getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.data)

  // later this token will be used for querying user-related data on my backend
  setToken(credential.googleIdToken)
}
```

**How I validate my endpoints on the backend side**

```
fun Application.installAuthentication() {
  val googleJwtIssuer = environment.config.property("jwt.google.domain").getString()
  val googleJwtAudience = environment.config.property("jwt.google.audience").getString()
  val jwtRealm = environment.config.property("jwt.google.realm").getString()
  val googleJwkProvider = JwkProviderBuilder(URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"))
    .cached(10, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .rateLimited(10, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build()
  install(Authentication) {
    jwt("google") {
      verifier(googleJwkProvider) {
        withIssuer(googleJwtIssuer)
        withAudience(googleJwtAudience)
      }
      realm = jwtRealm
      validate { credentials ->
        if (credentials.payload.audience.contains(googleJwtAudience))
          JWTPrincipal(credentials.payload)
        else
          null
      }
    }
  }
}

// in my main
installAuthentication()
routing {
  authenticate("google") {
    get("/get-todos") {
      val payload = call.principal<JWTPrincipal>()?.payload ?: error("JWTPrincipal not found")
      
      call.respond(getTodos(payload.subject))
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit

*Sample JWT returned by the google sign in API (on first sign in)*

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "secret",
  "aud": "secret",
  "sub": "secret",
  "email": "secret@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "Ben Jerry",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/secret",
  "given_name": "Patrik",
  "family_name": "Aradi",
  "locale": "en-GB",
  "iat": 1616243551,
  "exp": 1616247151
}
```

It does not have a refresh token in it unfortunatelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the old [GoogleSignInApi](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#check_for_an_existing_signed-in_user)'s silent sign in feature for this. I've tested and if I use the [New Google Sign In api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity) for the sign in, the old one will still be able to perform the silent sign in.

It would be nice, if the new one had this silent sign in feature, but for now it looks like if you would like this "refresh" feature, you're still required to use the old api.

Comment: Do you have any working sample that you could share?

Comment: Is this still the situation in 2022. I don't see a way with the "new" API to get a new token when the previous one expires.